# relation between correlation and value of pdf at $0$ for difference of 2 nonnegative random variables.

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are 2 non-negative continuous random variables following the same distribution with strictly positive pdf $f(x)$. assume it has all positive order moments and variance is 1.

Further assume correlation between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ is $\rho\in(-1,1)$ and their joint distribution is exchangeble (i.e. for any $a,b>0$, the joint pdf satisfies: $h(a,b)=h(b,a)$).

then I can see that $Y_1-Y_2$ are symmetric about $0$. Denote the pdf of $Y_1-Y_2$ as $g(\cdot)$, I'm wondering if it's true that $g(0)$ is bounded above by some positive constant depending on value of $\rho$? or if
$$\lim_{a\to 0}\frac{P(|Y_1-Y_2|<a)}{2a}\leq C_\rho$$ for some constant $C_\rho>0$ ?

Any hint will be appreciated!

Comment: The question does not make sense since pdf's are only defined almost everywhere.

Comment: sorry for the confusion.  I just editted the question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is that it is not bounded. Here is a sketch of an argument.

Let $U_1$ and $U_2$ be a random variables uniformly distributed over $[0,c^2]$ for some $0<c<1$, independent of each other and of $Y_1,Y_2$.

Then, starting with $Y_1, Y_2$ as defined above, define random variables $X_1, X_2$ as follows:

$$\text{ with probability } 1-c:\; X_1=Y_1, X_2=Y_2 $$
$$\text{ with probability } c: \; X_1=U_1, X_2=U_2$$

If we let $c$ get arbitrarily small, $X_1X_2$ will converge in distribution to $Y_1,Y_2$, but the density of $X_1-X_2$ close to zero will beome arbitrarily large.
$$\frac {P(|X_1 -X_2| < c^2)}{2c^2} \geq \frac{1}{c}$$